# OpenID check_authentication not working

Tags: php, openid

I'm trying to get a check_authentication response working, but so far, all consumers reject it and say that my server denied check_authentication.

This is the GET and POST data that my server file receives:

```
$_GET:
Array
(
    [mode] => profile
    [username] => hachque
    [domain] => roket-enterprises.com
)
$_POST:
Array
(
    [openid_assoc_handle] => {HMAC-SHA1}{4b00d7b2}{vo1FEQ==}
    [openid_identity] => http://www.roket-enterprises.com/openaccount/openid:hachque
    [openid_mode] => check_authentication
    [openid_response_nonce] => 2009-11-16T04:40:18Zrrz8R4
    [openid_return_to] => http://openiddirectory.com:80/openidauth/id/c/finish_auth.php?nonce=adCevd6T
    [openid_sig] => SgFE5iT9IGd5EftkrZ72mgCHiLk=
    [openid_signed] => assoc_handle,identity,mode,response_nonce,return_to,signed,sreg.email,sreg.fullname,sreg.nickname
    [openid_sreg_email] => jrhodes@roket-enterprises.com
    [openid_sreg_fullname] => James Rhodes
    [openid_sreg_nickname] => jrhodes
)
```

This is the header reponse that I am outputting (contains POST data as it was explained to me on IRC that sending the key-values as headers shouldn't be done to the consumer server **EDIT:** Come to think of it, it doesn't make much sense RESPONDING with POST data.  Maybe some here can explain the whole process of check_authentication clearly).

```
  Content-Type: text/plain;
  Content-Length: 675;
  openid.mode=id_res&openid.assoc_handle=%7BHMAC-SHA1%7D%7B4b00d7b2%7D%7Bvo1FEQ%3D%3D%7D&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.roket-enterprises.com%2Fopenaccount%2Fopenid%3Ahachque&openid.response_nonce=2009-11-16T04%3A40%3A18Zrrz8R4&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fopeniddirectory.com%3A80%2Fopenidauth%2Fid%2Fc%2Ffinish_auth.php%3Fnonce%3DadCevd6T&openid.signed=assoc_handle%2Cidentity%2Cmode%2Cresponse_nonce%2Creturn_to%2Csigned%2Csreg.email%2Csreg.fullname%2Csreg.nickname&openid.sreg_email=jrhodes%40roket-enterprises.com&openid.sreg_fullname=James+Rhodes&openid.sreg_nickname=jrhodes&openid.sig=MGVhMmQ1Mzg4ZWFlMWY1OWVlYjlmZmY0Njc3OTc5YWIzMjM3NGFjMQ%3D%3D&openid.is_valid=true;
```

---

This is the PHP code that my file is using to handle check_authentication (remember that PHP turns all . characters into _ for $_GET and $_POST variables since they aren't valid character in PHP array keys):

```
        // Retrieve the OpenID information from the $_REQUEST data
        // I'm not sure whether it's possible that this data might
        // come in on the $_GET parameter instead of $_POST, so that's
        // what it uses $_REQUEST.

        $assoc_handle = $_REQUEST['openid_assoc_handle'];
        $sig = $_REQUEST['openid_sig'];
        $signed = $_REQUEST['openid_signed'];

        // The method for returning data is via the headers outputted
        // by the webserver.  Create an array that stores the headers
        // to be returned.

        $keys = array(
            'openid.mode' => 'id_res',
            'openid.assoc_handle' => $_REQUEST['openid_assoc_handle'],
            'openid.identity' => $_REQUEST['openid_identity'],
            'openid.response_nonce' => $_REQUEST['openid_response_nonce'],
            'openid.return_to' => $_REQUEST['openid_return_to'],
            'openid.signed' => $_REQUEST['openid_signed'],
            'openid.sreg_email' => $_REQUEST['openid_sreg_email'],
            'openid.sreg_fullname' => $_REQUEST['openid_sreg_fullname'],
            'openid.sreg_nickname' => $_REQUEST['openid_sreg_nickname']
            //'openid_mode' => 'id_res'
        );

        // The server may request that we invalidate the user's session
        // via $_REQUEST['openid_invalidate_handle'].  In this case we
        // will clear the session data (you may need to change this
        // depending on how you implement the session).  After doing so
        // we continue and tell the server we did via a variable

        if (strlen($_REQUEST['openid_invalidate_handle']) > 0)
        {
            // Reset the session
            session_unset();
            session_name('openid_server');
            session_start();

            // Set the header we need to return
            $keys['openid.invalidate_handle'] = $_REQUEST['openid_invalidate_handle'];
        }

        // We need to validate the signature now.  This constructs a token_contents
        // for signing the data.  The signing key is returned as openid.sig
        // and is generated with base64(HMAC(secret(assoc_handle), token_contents)

        $token_contents = '';
        foreach (explode(',', $signed) as $param) {
            $post = preg_replace('/\./', '_', $param);
            $token_contents .= sprintf("%s:%s\n", $param, $_REQUEST['openid_' . $post]);
        }

        // Generate our openid.sig and add it to the list of keys to
        // return.

        $keys['openid.sig'] = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1',$token_contents,$assoc_handle));

        // Add the data that we are sharing (via SReg) to the headers.
        // For now this is fixed data (see action_authorization.php).
        //$keys["sreg.fullname"] = 'James Rhodes';
        //$keys["sreg.nickname"] = 'jrhodes';
        //$keys["sreg.email"] = 'jrhodes@roket-enterprises.com';

        // Just accept the request for now..
        // phpMyID does some kind of secret-shared-key thing
        // here to determine whether it is valid.  I'm not
        // quite sure how that process works yet, so we are just
        // going to say go ahead.
        $keys["openid.is_valid"] = "true";

        // We need to format the $keys array into POST format
        $keys_post = "";
        $keys_post_first = true;
        foreach ($keys as $name => $value)
        {
            if ($keys_post_first)
                $keys_post_first = false;
            else
                $keys_post .= "&";
            $keys_post .= urlencode($name) . "=" . urlencode($value);
        }

        // Now output the POST data
        header('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($keys_post));
        header($keys_post);
```

Can anyone help me with my problem?  I've been trying to get this working for months and I can't get a straight answer on how this stage of OpenID authentication is meant to work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, although PHP transforms periods to underscores in parameter names, be sure you're *sending* periods and not underscores.

Secondly, your check_authentication response should only have three parameters, but you have six.  [Check the spec](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#verifying_signatures) and fix up your response and see if that helps.

Comment: I checked the phpMyID code and it appears to add the SReg variables to the check_authentication response. I'll remove them and try again though. I checked with Firefox's Live HTTP Headers and I am sending periods in the headers.

Comment: Besides the extra sreg parameters, you have extra openid.mode and openid_mode parameters (neither should be present).  And probably most importantly, you're *missing* the `ns` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Arnott,you're wrong!
documentation from openid.net:

11.4.2.1.  Request Parameters

openid.mode
Value: "check_authentication"

Exact copies of all fields from the authentication response, except for "openid.mode".

may be more than three fields!

Comment: Dont confuse people. "authentication response" is other response. Response on "check_authentication", should be 3 fields, like is_valid

Comment: I now only have

openid.mode
is_valid

yet it still says that the server has denied check_authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case, the client (relying party) failed to resolve the name of the OpenId provider to the correct ip. Although this is unlikely to be the case, please check name resolution on your relying server.